# Django filter datetime based on month and day only in a range

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filters

I am trying to filter model objects in between a certain range. If I consider the year then I am able to do it fine like below:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
start_date = today + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
end_date = today + datetime.timedelta(days = 7)

for required_day in required_days:
        filter_dict.update({
                        required_day + "__range" : [start_date, end_date]
                        })

list_of_Q = [Q(**{key: val}) for key, val in filter_dict.items()]

if list_of_Q:
    model_objects = Model.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, list_of_Q))
```

But what I would like to do is to filter only by the values of `day` and `month` of the `datetime`.

I tried as below:

```
for required_day in required_days:
        filter_dict.update({
                        required_day + "__month__gte" : start_date.month,
                        required_day + "__day__gte" : start_date.day,
                        required_day + "__month__lte" : end_date.month,
                        required_day + "__day__lte" : end_date.day,
                        })
```

But I am not getting the correct values here. How can I rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in `list_of_Q` each item in `filter_dict` was considered separately. So when I used `reduce` on `list_of_Q`, it was filtering considering each `required_day`'s `start_date` and `end_date` separately.

So the solution that I wrote is as below:

```
filter_list = []

for required_day in required_days:
    filter_list.append(Q(**{
                    required_day + "__month__gte" : start_date.month,
                    required_day + "__day__gte" : start_date.day,
                    required_day + "__month__lte" : end_date.month,
                    required_day + "__day__lte" : end_date.day,
                    }))

if filter_list:
    #continue with the logic
```

Now this adds `Q` objects for each `required_day` as a whole.